# Waiting for Subcription to finish in Angular

Tags: angular

I am doing a data share between multiple components using a service.
Here, in the service, i have a getter where i am initializing the base data and have a subject which notifies the other components for any change.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ExpenseHandlerService {
  expenseDataChanged = new Subject<ExpenseDetails>();

  private expenseData: Array<ExpenseDetails> = [];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  /**
   * Fetched expense data and stored in the this.expenseData
   */
  getExpenseData() {
    console.log("Starting...");
    this.http
      .get("assets/model/data.json")
      .pipe(map(result => result))
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.expenseData = data as Array<ExpenseDetails>;
        console.log(this.expenseData);
      });
    return this.expenseData.slice();
  }

  /**
   * Notifies other components of any change in the data
   *
   * @param data
   */
  addExpenseData(data: ExpenseDetails) {
    //console.log(this.expenseData.length);
    //this.expenseData.push(data);
    this.expenseDataChanged.next(data);
    //console.log(this.expenseData);
  }
}
```

I have declared a component which makes use of the getExpenseData method to initialize the existing data.

The init method for the component is as follows:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.expenseData = this.expenseHandlerService.getExpenseData();
  this.expenseHandlerService.expenseDataChanged.subscribe(res => {
    this.receiveExpenseData(res);
  });
}
```

But when the app is being executed, i am getting just the empty array which i have defined and after the ngOnInit has been executed, the subcriber in the service completes and logs the actual data.

As i am trying to have the service as a central communication link between few components, i want to have the api call in the service itself.

Comment: FYI `.pipe(map(result => result))` is totally pointless.

Comment: But you have api cal inside of your service. For me, your question is not clear what you would like to achieve. You get initial empty array because your code is executed synchronously.

Comment: @Stefan I have a api call inside a service which initializes the existing data, i want this call to be completed in the service and then want to send the copy of this data to the component

Comment: For example you can call this getExpenseData in route resolver that it will be ready when your component is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to fix the issue (i.e. resolver/guard) but I will propose a solution as per your current code. You should call `ExpenseHandlerService.getExpenseData` in the constructor of the `ExpenseHandlerService`. Also, change your `expenseDataChanged` type to `BehaviorSubject`. Having said that let's change the `ExpenseHandlerService` like this [See the code comments for the explaination]:

```
@Injectable(
  {
    providedIn: 'root'
  }
)
export class ExpenseHandlerService {

  //I think BehaviorSubject type should be Array<ExpenseDetails> instead of ExpenseDetails
  //As your question was not clear so I am assuming as Aray<ExpenseDetails>; If you want type as ExpenseDetails
  //then you will have to adjust the code accordinlgy
  //LETS KEEP THIS VARIABLE AS PRIVATE SO THAT NOONE FROM OUTSIDE CAN EMIT NEW VALUE
  //AND EXPOSE AN OBSERVABLE as public property [see below]
  private expenseDataChanged = new BehaviorSubject<Array<ExpenseDetails>>([]);

  //This should be subscribed by the consumers i.e. Components
  get expenseDataObs() {
     return this.expenseDataChanged.asObservable();
  }

  //NO NEED TO MAINTAIN THIS ARRAY AS BehaviorSubject.value will give us the last emitted array
  //private expenseData: Array<ExpenseDetails> = [];
  constructor( private http: HttpClient) {

    this.getExpenseData();

  }
/**
 * Fetched expense data and stored in the this.expenseData
 */
  getExpenseData() {
    console.log('Starting...');
    this.http.get("assets/model/data.json")
      .pipe(map(result => result)).subscribe(data => {

      //I AM NOT SURE IF YOU API CAN RETURN NULL OR NOT
      //STILL IF API RETURNS NULL THEN EMIT EMPTY ARRAY
      //ADJUST THIS CODE AS PER YOUR APP LOGIC
      if(!data) {
       data = [];
      }
      const arr = data as Array<ExpenseDetails>;

      //I AM NOT USING SLICE (with no argument will return same array) AS IT WAS NOT DOING ANYTHING;
      //IF YOU WANT TO USE THEN USE AS PER YOUR LOGIC
      this.expenseDataChanged.next(arr);
    });

  }

/**
 * Notifies other components of any change in the data
 *
 * @param data
 */
  addExpenseData(data: ExpenseDetails) {

    //Get the last emited array from behaviorsubject
    const lastEmittedArr = this.expenseDataChanged.value;

    //push the data in to newArray
    //NOTICE I AM CREATING NEW ARRAY - This is to make sure that array is rendered; again it is NOT mandatory
    //but it depends on kind of changedetection stretegy is used.
    const newArrayToEmit = [...lastEmittedArr, data];
    this.expenseDataChanged.next(newArrayToEmit);
  }
}
```

Now in your component, subscribe to `expenseDataObs` like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.expenseHandlerService.expenseDataObs
        .pipe(

          //As soon as you subscribe the initial value could be an null because the Behavior subject was initialized with null
          //THIS IS BECAUSE OF THE NATURE OF BehaviorSubject; It may happen because by the time you subscribe
          //response of HTTP API might not have recieved; but as soon as it is received
          //Using the filter will ensure to avoid null in callback
          filter(arr => !!arr)
        )
        .subscribe((res) => {

      //Process the array recieved;
      this.receiveExpenseData(res);
    });
  }
```

**NOTE: In the above approach there could be the possibility that by the time component initialized there will be no data rendered until HTTP response comes back. So the user may see a blank page. To avoid that either you show a loader or use resolver/guard to load the data.**

[Personally, I use some sort of store i.e. NGRX/NGXS/AKITA for the state management instead of managing the state in the services].

Hope it helps.